# FirebaseApp.configure() Thread 1: Signal SIGBART

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm doing some stuff with Firebase and Cloud Messaging.

And the problem is I need to call application.registerForRemoteNotifications() BEFORE FirebaseApp.configure().
I've read that it should solve my problem.

I work with project I got from employer and FirebaseApp.configure() is called this way:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

I don't know why it is so.

And application.registerForRemoteNotifications() is called in application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions). Here what I have:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //        FirebaseApp.configure()
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyCWMU53OSR4zO28i9e2BsASnda3X1TAS2Y")
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyCWMU53OSR4zO28i9e2BsASnda3X1TAS2Y")
    UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent, animated: true)


    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.clear], for: .selected)




    print("Token is ", Messaging.messaging().fcmToken)


    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.0)

    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: { (granted, err) in
            //                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        })
    } else {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .alert, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}
```

And the **problem is** when I try to put `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the beginning of the `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` I get

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.

**From console I get**:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp
>   instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be
>   initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];`
>   is called in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.'

I can't understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

First, **FirebaseApp.configure()** has to be in the very first line in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    ...
```

.

After that, you do all the registration things.

```
    ...
    // Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.0) // why do you need a sleep here?
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: { (granted, err) in
           application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        })
    } else {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .alert, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I still get Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT with the same output in the console